# Compile a ".vue" component in browser, with JS only?

Tags: vue.js, components

I'd like to compile ".vue" components (with contains html/js/css) into JS, but in browser side, without browserify/vuify/webpack or others ...

In a better world, i'd like to include my ".vue" component into my html app, like that, withoud need of compile things, server side:

```
<script type="vuejs/component" src="myComp.vue"></script>
```

It should be possible ?! no ?
(And I can't imagine that no one got this idea, or have done it already)

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 23):

In fact, it's possible with http-vue-loader :

https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader

Comment: ...and https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader for Vue3

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make sense to compile in the browser when it's so much more efficient to just pre-compile your component locally instead of relying on a visitor's client to do it.

In fact, the answer above regarding vue-http-loader says it's only for use in development and links to this article: https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/

With that said, I created a vue-cli template that lets you pre-compile `.vue` files into a single `.js` files you can use in the browser.  The single JS file contains the template, script, and styles. It uses webpack, but it's super easy to run and watches your files as you edit them.

`$ vue init RonnieSan/vue-browser-sfc my-project`

Repo at: https://github.com/RonnieSan/vue-browser-sfc

Instructions are in the README.

Comment: Great, you should create an online webservice able to transform a ".vue" in a reusable JS ....

Comment: In fact there is a very good reason why to compile in the Browser: I have an in-browser editor where I can create/edit client side modules and view the changes instantly, I would like to do that with vue templates as well.

Comment: This is mightily useful!... thank for creating this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vue-import` in browser，like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>vue-import</title>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js",
        "vue-import": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-import/dist/vue-import.esm-browser.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" v-cloak>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </div>
  <script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue';
    import vueImport from 'vue-import';

    const app = createApp();
    app.component('my-component', await vueImport('myComp.vue'))

    app.mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

https://github.com/kianfang/vue-import

The production package size is less than 1kB.