# webpack and vue async component from different project / domain

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm pretty new on webpack, I already watch some tutorials and get a working configuration on my project.

I try to load vuejs components asynchronously in this way:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <component
      :is="template"
    >
    </component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed: {
    template () {
      return () => import(`@/templates/${this.$template.name}`)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.template().then(comp => {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        //...
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

After webpack compilation, I get three files:

- app.js
- 0.js
- index.html

this is the result I want, because this will be a widget, so just one js file inclusion (app.js) which calls 0.js during its execution, and it works well when app.js is included on the index.html page on the same host

But how can I do if I want to include app.js file from another host?

For example if I have mywebsite.com/index.html which includes app.js script

```
<!--https://mywebsite.com/index.html-->
<script src="https://my_widget_host.com/app.js"></script>
```

I get a 404 error when it tries to get the 0.js file, because the calls is on http://mywebsite.com/0.js and not on http://my_widget_host.com/0.js

Is there a way to prefix `0.js` file with the url of the server which hosts the file?

Comment: You would probably be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336623/use-cdn-components-with-a-cli-build/50695532#50695532

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's why publicPath (https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) was invented. You can set it on build time, or more conveniently on run-time - just assign window.**webpack_public_path** = 'https://my_widget_host.com/';

Regards.

Comment: This also works if your components are getting compiled into a folder like /js/dist/ and you are using prefetching. Thanks for this.