# Vue.js async component loading from different subdomain

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project and I would like to know how can I configure webpack to load javascript chunks from a different subdomain?

For example if there is a site on `www.mysite.com` and it loads javascript assets from `static.mysite.com`.

My webpack.min.js file looks like this:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/file1.js',
    'resources/assets/js/file2.js',
], staticBuildPath + '/js/main.js')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            chunkFilename: "js/[id].chunk.js"
        }
     });
```

But the problem is it wants to load chunk files from `www.mysite.com`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack and vue async component from different project / domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916512/webpack-and-vue-async-component-from-different-project-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/file1.js',
    'resources/assets/js/file2.js',
], staticBuildPath + '/js/main.js')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            chunkFilename: "js/[id].chunk.js",
            publicPath: '//' + process.env.DOMAINS_STATIC + '/'
        }
     });
```

where `DOMAINS_STATIC` is one of my env variables in .env file and it contains the proper domain, which is `static.mysite.com` in this case.